# Rating bar showing only half stars instead of full stars

Tags: android, android-widget, rating

I'm working on an app that needs to create a non editable small style rating bar with 4 stars dynamically.

When I call `setRating(4)` it shows 4 stars without any problem.
But when I call `setRating(3)` it shows 3 and half stars.
`setRating(2)` shows 2 stars correctly,
but `setrating(1)` shows 1 and half stars.

When I use a normal rating bar in another activity it works fine, but when I use the small style non editable rating bar it doesn't work properly.

Does this have anything to do with the api level or small style non editable rating bar?

Initialization is done like this:

```
RatingBar ioRatingBar = new RatingBar(this,null,android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
ioRatingBar.setNumStars(4);

ioRatingBar.setRating(3);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to [set the step size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setStepSize%28float%29) of the `RatingBar` like this

```
ratingBar.setStepSize(1.0);
```

and also try to define the [max rating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setMax%28int%29) as:

```
ratingBar.setMax(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If exist `padding`, remove. I suggest replace with `margin`.